# Solving a set of linear systems in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having a problem understanding the working mechanism of tensorflow's function: tf.linalg.solve.
I want to solve a set of linear systems (AX = Y), where the linear coefficients (A) were shared but there are multiple batches of Y, which are different.
Using numpy, I can simply do it via:

```
np.random.seed(0)
mtx = np.random.uniform(size= (1,4,4))
vec = np.random.uniform(size= (100,4,1))
solution = np.linalg.solve(mtx,vec)
print(abs(np.matmul(mtx,solution) - vec).max())
# 5.551115123125783e-16
```

which gives me a quite consistent solution.
But when I switch to tensorflow, it gives me the results:

```
mtx = tf.random.uniform(shape = (1,4,4))
vec = tf.random.uniform(shape = (100,4,1))
solution = tf.linalg.solve(mtx,vec)
print(tf.math.reduce_max(abs(tf.matmul(mtx,solution) - vec))) 
# tf.Tensor(1.3136615, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

According to the document, I assume the solution should be solved according to the corresponding vec. But it does not seem to give me the expected results in tensorflow. Since I'm a new user, I could have messed up something.
It would be appreciated if any information could be offered.

Answer (score 2):

The first dimension is the batch dimension in Tesorflow, see
[the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/solve).

```py
mtx = tf.random.uniform(shape = (5, 4, 4))
vec = tf.random.uniform(shape = (5, 4, 1))
solution = tf.linalg.solve(mtx, vec)
print(solution.shape)
# TensorShape([5, 4, 1])
print(tf.math.reduce_max(abs(tf.matmul(mtx, solution) - vec))) 
# tf.Tensor(5.1259995e-06, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: does it mean I have to repeat the coefficient matrix and it would not be broadcasted automatically?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you have a single 4x4-matrix and 100 4-vectors. Thus 100 linear systems to solve with the same matrix. Just use shapes [1,4,4] for mtx and [1,4,100] fir vec. Or simply [4,4] and [4,100] correspondingly.